# Google Charts calls JSON

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

So I came up with the simple chart example using Google chart.
This is my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
<title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src='https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
      "modules":[{
        "name":"visualization",
        "version":"1"
      }]
    }'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
  function drawVisualization() {
    // Define the chart using setters:
    var wrap = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();
    wrap.setChartType('LineChart');
    wrap.setDataSourceUrl('http://amr2.mybluemix.net/getmet/list');
    wrap.setContainerId('visualization');
    wrap.setQuery('SELECT d.uSN,d.timetag WHERE d.hourtag < 1 ORDER BY d.timetag');
    wrap.setOptions({'title':'Population Density (people/km^2)', 'legend':'none'});
    wrap.draw();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='visualization' style='height: 400px; width: 400px;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is to retrieve the JSON from this http://amr2.mybluemix.net/getmet/list and visualize them in google chart.

Is anybody can show me what I have been missing?

Answer (score 1):

As it seems the requested ressource doesn't support the Chart Tools Datasource protocol, the data will be returned as plain object(not a dataTable), regardless of the  passed QUERY-parameters.

What you can do: request the data via AJAX, and create the dataTable on your own based on the returned data.